# Stored procedure XML parsing performance

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance, t-sql, parsing

I have a SP with an XML variable parsing code part.

The XML has got the next structure:

```
<root>
  <ID Reason="1">1</ID>
  <ID Reason="2">2</ID>
  <ID Reason="2">3</ID>
  <ID Reason="1">5</ID>
</root>
```

SP code part:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_table (ID,Reason)
SELECT IDs.ID.value('.', 'int')
     , IDs.ID.value('@Reason', 'int')
FROM @I_XML.nodes('/root/ID') AS Ids(ID)
```

When I try run SP with XML input parameter that have 100000 rows it takes a crazy amount of time and the execution cost is 5%.

How can I improve the SP code part to make it faster?

Comment: If the XML looks like that, is there a reason the caller can't pass in a table-valued parameter instead?

Comment: No, I can't change the type of input parameter

Comment: I would not worry about the execution cost but "crazy amount of time" sounds kind of serious. How much time is that actually? In the tests I made on a laptop your query took 2 seconds and with the rewrite in my answer it took 1.5 second. The OPENXML version took 4 seconds.

Comment: Are you using Sql Server 2005?  There is a "element based xml shredding" bug out there, FYI.

Comment: As stated elsewhere, I prefer to create a @variable or #temp table...shred the xml into it..........then hit the "real" table.  Separate the 2 actions, the shredding, then the CUD'ing.

Comment: If "*..execution cost is 5%..*", then that's not the part that is causing your problem. Nor should it, IME, this query should perform well (actually Mikael Eriksson's point is well-taken, "." can misbehave sometimes). Check the rest of your SP.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to change how you fetch the node values.

```sql
INSERT INTO #tmp_table (ID,Reason)
SELECT IDs.ID.value('text()[1]', 'int')
     , IDs.ID.value('@Reason', 'int')
FROM @I_XML.nodes('/root/ID') AS Ids(ID)
```

By specifying the `text()` node you will get a slightly different execution plan without changing the result. Using only a node name (`.` in your case) will make SQL Server do a deep search for all node values under the specified node. In your XML there are none so the result will be the same.

Comment: Do I need to add text() for @Reason ? No ?

Comment: @Aleksandr No, attribute is singel values only and can not be a parent node to other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OPENXML`:

```
declare @hXml int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hXml output, @YourXmlParam

insert into #tmp_table
select ID, Reason
from OPENXML(@hXml, '/root/ID') with (ID int '.', Reason int '@Reason')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hXml
```

Comment: This is Sql Server 2000 syntax that was replaced in 2005.

Comment: It was not replaced, and still actual ([even in 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)). In some cases it is faster than using `nodes()` and `value()`, but in this case I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, "replaced" wasn't the correct word I guess.  "Updated" and "kept for backwards compatibility".  But you're right, every so often you might find a case where it performs better just based on the xml structure and size.